# rostest error: Test Fixture Nodes failed to launch

Tags: rostest

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. I am a newbie on ROS.
I tried to test some codes with rostest, but error occured.
Would you give me some clues to fix it?
Thank you.
The error message is:

```
mech-user@test1-pc:~/2015-soft3/20150930/src/beginner_tutorial$ rostest ./check1.test
... logging to /home/mech-user/.ros/log/rostest-test1-pc-7453.log
[ROSUNIT] Outputting test results to /home/mech-user/.ros/test_results/beginner_tutorial/rostest-check1.xml
testtalker_listener ... FAILURE!
FAILURE: Test Fixture Nodes ['talker', 'listener'] failed to launch
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 331, in run
    testMethod()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rostest/runner.py", line 120, in fn
    self.assert_(not failed, "Test Fixture Nodes %s failed to launch"%failed)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 424, in assertTrue
    raise self.failureException(msg)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[ROSTEST]-----------------------------------------------------------------------

[testtalker_listener][failed]

SUMMARY
 * RESULT: FAIL
 * TESTS: 0
 * ERRORS: 0
 * FAILURES: 1

ERROR: The following tests failed to run:
 * testtalker_listener

rostest log file is in /home/mech-user/.ros/log/rostest-test1-pc-7453.log
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219053/rostest-error:-test-fixture-nodes-failed-to-launch/) by [Heecheol Kim](https://answers.ros.org/users/24457/heecheol-kim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2015-10-13

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-10-13**:
It looks like there's an error in your test file. Please edit your question to include your `check1.test` file.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2022-01-18**:
I got the `Test Fixture Nodes` error I think because the nodes were from a package not installed on the system (jenkins CI), adding their package to `<test_depend>` appeared to fix it.

(It seems to be the general rule with automated tests in cloud CI that useful error messages are put somewhere inaccessible like a log file that the user can't access, you can't ssh into CI runner to view them, or in the best case are somewhere in the middle of thousands of lines of CI console output...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, I didn't have authority of test files. I solve the problem with chmod -x . I appreciate for your concern.

---

Originally posted by [Heecheol Kim](https://answers.ros.org/users/24457/heecheol-kim/) with karma: 46 on 2015-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cst0](https://answers.ros.org/users/92869/cst0/) on 2022-01-18**:
Do you mean `chmod +x`? `-x` removes the permission to execute, but it sounds like you needed to add it.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OP seems to have solved the issue already. I add some info in case this helps future readers since I was just stuck with this error for a few hours.

> ```
> Test Fixture Nodes ['talker', 'listener']
> ```

The listed names are the nodes' name, the ones that are specified in `.launch` or in `.test` file as `name`.
Note as it states `fixture`, these nodes are not necessarily the ones testcases are defined in; these can be the ones to setup the environment for the tests.

(In my case because the `node` name was used in other places in my package multiple times, which is apprently a bad habit though, and because I didn't pay attention to this error message that clearly stated as "fixture", it was difficult to boil down the root cause.)

I thought I'd improve `rostest` code, but after taking a look at it, I concluded that actually the error message succintly provides enough info so I decided not to suggest any change.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2017-03-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1